# Bash history with timestamps

Tags: bash, osx, command-history

I would like to keep timestamps on the commands logged in my Bash $HISTFILE, is it possible?

I did not manage to set it up using `man bash` as an information source.

My other options are as follows:

```
function thebanana() {
  local -r -a bash_commands=(
    "ls"
    # ... more coconut commands
  )
  for bash_command in "${bash_commands[@]}"; do
    printf "${bash_command}"
    printf ":"
  done
}
export HISTFILE=banana
export HISTIGNORE="$(thebanana)"
export HISTSIZE=999999
export HISTFILESIZE=999999999
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
```

I should have mentioned I am on OS X Mountain Lion (sigh). `uname -a` gives me:

```
Darwin CoconutMac.local 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

and `echo $BASH_VERSION` gives me:

```
3.2.48(1)-release
```

Tried adding this:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%b %d %I:%M:%S %p '
```

and it only prefixes this kind of timestamps to commands:

```
#1349057791
```

I try echoing back the variable (`echo $HISTTIMEFORMAT`), it has the right value.

Interesting!

I even removed .profile completely to debug this. Still only funny timestamps:

```
#1349058320
```

I don't know how to further troubleshoot this... :(

**Solution**: I was using a script that reads the $HISTFILE directly, not the history built-in so the epoch-based timestamp (secs since Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970) was not being translated using the date formatting string. Plain-old `history` works fine, I'll use that instead.

Comment: Have you tried setting [`HISTTIMEFORMAT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-HISTTIMEFORMAT)?

Comment: Probably I am getting the strftime format wrong. It would help if the man page included at least a couple of examples.. +%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, put this in `~/.bashrc` :

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

Then, run the following commands :

```
. ~/.bashrc
history
```

It will look like this :

```
 (...)
 5200  2012-09-30 23:55:37 find -printf '%Ts %f\n'
 5201  2012-10-01 00:00:58 ls
 5202  2012-10-01 00:03:45 cd
 (...)
```

Explanations of the output :

- first col is the unique `id`
- second one is the date, third is the hour
- latest is your command line

Comment: Nope, doesn't work on OSX.. :( Prob that's the issue. A strange OS.

Comment: Did you `source ~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: I most definitely did. It is doing "something": adding a commented line _before_ the command with a numeric timestamp: #1349057149

Comment: The only ressource I've found accordingly to this is http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33970/setting-time-format-preference-in-unix-mac-terminal (search for HISTTIMEFORMAT)

Comment: Copied that HISTTIMEFORMAT='%b %d %I:%M:%S %p ' verbatim, still no luck. If I echo $HISTTIMEFORMAT it's the right value. This is interesting!

Comment: @Robottinosino Yes the commented line is the expected format.  To display the commands with formatted time, use the `history` builtin command, don't look at the history file directly.

Comment: Added some details & explanations

Comment: Worked like a charm for me on Mac OS X 10.9.5, here is a gist which includes session output: https://gist.github.com/jaytaylor/b7488b23455701da422a

Comment: Is it possible to have the time stamp in the history file recorded using HISTTIMEFORMAT?  I never use the `history` command, instead I use a text editor to find commands I'm looking for, and it would be nice to have a human readable date reference.