# bash history that stores execution time?

Tags: bash, command-history, time

Is it possible to have your bash history save the **total execution time** of every command you run?

i.e. as if every command were prefaced with 'time' and the result was stored in the history along with the command?

clarification: I already know that you can add a timestamp of when the command was started - but I would like to know the *total execution time*, not just when it was started.

Comment: not a duplicate - see clarification

Comment: Ah, OK, I'd understood "actual execution time" as "time at which the command was executed".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash history with timestamps](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49559/bash-history-with-timestamps)

Comment: @tecraf - not a duplicate - see clarification

Answer (score 1):

By defining HISTTIMEFORMAT in your startup scripts, you will have a timestamp added to every line of your bash history file. The value of this variable is the way (*) timestamps must be printed on the screen. Here is mine :

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F-%T '
```

(*) See `man 3 strftime` (if you don't have it, `man date` should do the trick)

Comment: yes, that will tell you what time you ran the command - but not the total execution time of it.

Comment: @slashdottir Sorry, I must have misread your question. I don't know of any such feature.

Answer (score 1):

Child process usage is set somewhere within the `wait3` or `wait4` system calls via a `struct rusage` pointer ([`wait4(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait4)). Under [the bash sources](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/bash/), we find:

```
$ egrep -r 'wait[34][[:blank:]]*\(' .
./jobs.c:   wait3 ((union wait *)statusp, options, (struct rusage *)0)
./jobs.c:   wait3 (statusp, options, (struct rusage *)0)
./jobs.c:   wait3 (statusp, options, (int *)0)
$
```

The blank `(struct rusage *)0` indicates that the resource usage will not be returned to `bash`. A `struct rusage` search does turn up `time_command` function in `execute_cmd.c`, and this does appear to collect usage information via [`getrusage(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage). However, this is for the `TIMEFORMAT` of the `time` builtin, and does not appear to intersect with the history code. Without patching `bash`, I guess you'd have to do some sort of kluge involving running everything under `time` and then capturing the standard error the time information appears on to some file?

Comment: I'm not above a good kluge ...  :)