# Adding timestamps to bash history on unix

Tags: command-history

I've been trying to add timestamps to my bash history on Mac, but it isn't really working. I put the following in both ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc and neither seem to work:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%m/%d/%y %T"
```

I then ran `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bashrc`, but only the number of the command seems to get printed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash history with timestamps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49559/bash-history-with-timestamps)